# How to identify the shape of a floorplan?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, shapes

I'm trying to differentiate between two different styles of houses using a floorplan. I'm very new to `cv2`, so I'm struggling a bit here. I'm able to identify the exterior of the house using contours using the code below, that is from another Stack Overflow response.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def find_rooms(img, noise_removal_threshold=25, corners_threshold=0.1,
               room_closing_max_length=100, gap_in_wall_threshold=500):
    assert 0 <= corners_threshold <= 1
    # Remove noise left from door removal

    img[img < 128] = 0
    img[img > 128] = 255
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(~img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    mask = np.zeros_like(img)
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area > noise_removal_threshold:
            cv2.fillPoly(mask, [contour], 255)

    img = ~mask

    # Detect corners (you can play with the parameters here)
    dst = cv2.cornerHarris(img ,2,3,0.04)
    dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)
    corners = dst > corners_threshold * dst.max()

    # Draw lines to close the rooms off by adding a line between corners on the same x or y coordinate
    # This gets some false positives.
    # You could try to disallow drawing through other existing lines for example.
    for y,row in enumerate(corners):
        x_same_y = np.argwhere(row)
        for x1, x2 in zip(x_same_y[:-1], x_same_y[1:]):

            if x2[0] - x1[0] < room_closing_max_length:
                color = 0
                cv2.line(img, (x1, y), (x2, y), color, 1)

    for x,col in enumerate(corners.T):
        y_same_x = np.argwhere(col)
        for y1, y2 in zip(y_same_x[:-1], y_same_x[1:]):
            if y2[0] - y1[0] < room_closing_max_length:
                color = 0
                cv2.line(img, (x, y1), (x, y2), color, 1)


    # Mark the outside of the house as black
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(~img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contour_sizes = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours]
    biggest_contour = max(contour_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]
    mask = np.zeros_like(mask)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, [biggest_contour], 255)
    img[mask == 0] = 0


    return biggest_contour, mask



#Read gray image

img = cv2.imread("/content/51626-7-floorplan-2.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ext_contour, mask = find_rooms(img.copy())
cv2_imshow(mask)
print('exterior')
epsilon = 0.01*cv2.arcLength(ext_contour,True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(ext_contour,epsilon,True)
final = cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2_imshow(final)
```

These floorplans will only have one of two shapes, a 6 sided shape and a 4 sided shape. Below are the two styles:

[image: 6 sided house]

[image: 4 sided house]

I need to ignore any bay windows or small extrusions.

I believe the next step is to only have a contour for the main walls, have that contour be smooth, and then count the edges in the array. I'm stuck as to how to do this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Threshold your images or use contours, then use matchShapes(). See https://www.learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/ and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317

Answer (score 0):

- Simple contour finding is unlikely to give you a robust solution.
  however your current approach can be improved by first calculating a mask of the white background.

Using the shape of this mask you can determine the layout.

```
lower_color_bounds = cv.Scalar(255, 255, 255)
upper_color_bounds = cv.Scalar(220, 220, 220)

mask = cv2.inRange(frame,lower_color_bounds,upper_color_bounds )
mask_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really just need the decision, whether it's a four or six sided house, you can simply do the following: Grayscale image, and inverse binary threshold everything, which is not nearly white. Then, just calculate the ratio between that mask and the total number of pixels. That ratio must be larger for four sided houses than for six sided houses. The exact cut-off depends on your data. For the two given examples, one could set the cut-off to `0.9`.

Here's some code:

```py
import cv2
from skimage import io      # Only needed for web grabbing images


def house_analysis(image):

    # Grayscale image
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Inverse binary threshold everything, which is not nearly white
    mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 248, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

    # Calculate ratio between mask and total number of pixels
    ratio = cv2.countNonZero(mask) / (mask.shape[0] * mask.shape[1])
    print(ratio)

    # Decide with respect to cut-off, if house is four or six sided
    cutoff = 0.9
    if ratio > cutoff:
        print('Four sided house')
    else:
        print('Six sided house')

    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


house_4 = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqzZB.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
house_6 = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpkQW.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

house_analysis(house_4)
house_analysis(house_6)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The `print` outputs:

```
0.9533036597428289
Four sided house
0.789531416400426
Six sided house
```

If you have larger white space around the main walls, one could crop that part to get more robust ratios.

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:  Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:    3.8.1
OpenCV:    4.1.2
----------------------------------------
```